# CSS - how to use modular scale for font size

Tags: css, frontend, font-size, typography

I have a Modular Scale with multi ratios (1.5 & 1.25):

http://www.modularscale.com/?16&px&1.5,1.25&web&text

I don't know what should I fill in my css to set font-size follow the above type scale. I think it should be:

```
p{ font-size: 1em; }
h4{ font-size: 1.25em; }
h3{ font-size: 1.5em; }
h2{ font-size: 1.563em; }
h1{ font-size: 1.953em; }
```

Is it right? And how can we determine the line-height value?

Thank you.

Comment: Or, you can leave them as is.

Comment: You might use CSS Vars + calc to have the values calculated instead of hard coded floating values. (yes I should add an example)

Answer (score -1):

```
p{ font-size: 1em; }
h4{ font-size: 1.25em; }
h3{ font-size: 1.5em; }
h2{ font-size: 1.563em; }
h1{ font-size: 1.953em; }
```

it is right way to determine and u should have to mention the line-height in css body

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. In my view this answer is not explaining it good enough. Also no difference to example in question.